# Is it possible to change the package management system?

Tags: package-management, deb, rpm

I took a look at CentOS recently and was amazed, but I also remembered dabbling in Fedora when release 16 came out and recall being horrified by the awfulness of rpm. I cannot stand anything other than ubuntu's package management system.
Seeing rpm again in such a good setup as CentOS though, got me thinking again.

**Can you change the package management system? Or is it in the core and require rebuilding the entire OS?**

*Please don't answer with "You can uninstall synaptic and use USC", I have no in depth knowledge of package management but I'm not on about using a different GUI or something.
Is it possible to do the above and make rpm's native on ubuntu or deb's on fedora (and I don't need to know about Alien either, which converts deb's to rpm's and vice versa).*

Comment: are you willing to change the package repository, too? (good question though if then it would be still ubuntu or not)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can not use yum on Debian/Ubuntu is because of incompatibility of the packages.

Lets assume for a minute you removed apt and installed yum from source code. Where then would you get a package to install ? You could no longer use the Ubuntu repositories as all the packages are .deb.

Look at the packaging guides

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines

The structure is completely different and there is no reliable tool to convert a .deb to a .rpm

So if you are going to then use the Fedora repos, why not just install Fedora ?

And if you are going to go with source code, better off with Arch, gentoo, or Linux from scratch.

Comment: Hey thanks! I was just wondering as I'm very interested in one day doing a 'linux from scratch' and building my own distro.

I like deb's best but enjoy distro's that use otherwise, and with ubuntu going down the pan for me I'm looking at my options.

Thanks again for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible?" is a huge question, and I am sure there are probably a few genius hackers out there who could do it. But, in general, I think the answer to your question is No.

Comment: I understand. Firstly I just wanted to know if there was some kind of deeper incompatibility that would completely prevent this. Thank you :)